# Iterative Fibonacci sequence

Tags: beginner, c, fibonacci-sequence

I implemented a function that prints all the numbers from the Fibonacci sequence until `max_num`. The minimum value allowed is 0 (so, fib(0) prints 1). It works until 92, and I want to know how to improve the code, in general.

```
void fib(unsigned int max_num)
{
    unsigned long fib_num = 1;
    unsigned long fib_temp = 0;
    size_t count = 0;

    if (max_num < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Please, enter a non-negative number\n");
        return;
    }

    for (; count <= max_num; count++)
    {
        printf("%lu\n", fib_num);
        fib_num += fib_temp;
        fib_temp = fib_num - fib_temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider documenting this function with something like [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/index.html). At a quick glance, your function can be interpreted two different ways: Print out `fib(0)`, `fib(1)`, ..., or print out all Fibonacci numbers less than or equal to `max_num`. Documentation will clarify that.

`max_num` will never be negative. It is defined as an `unsigned int`, which means it can never hold a negative value. So this:

```
if (max_num < 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Please, enter a non-negative number\n");
    return;
}
```

will never happen. (Try calling `fib(-2)`, see what happens)

(Optional) Put `size_t count = 0` inside the loop if you can? ([You may have to add `-std=c99` or something like that to make it work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24884/667648))

```
for (size_t count = 0; count <= max_num; count++)
{
    printf("%lu\n", fib_num);
    fib_num += fib_temp;
    fib_temp = fib_num - fib_temp;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I heard some people saying I should stick to the c89 mode. In your opinion, which one is the best?

Comment: It has a lot to do with how much of the market supports the language... It may have been at the time a better idea to use C89 over C99 because very few compilers supported C99. This isn't true anymore. It might even be better to use C11.  (Which I believe is `-std=c11`). A large part is do you need to support C89? C99? If not, I would just do C99, the `for`-loop syntax for C89 is particularly annoying to me.

Comment: For reference there are answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11926008/667648

That coincide with my comment.

Comment: @LúcioCardoso The only more or less relevant compiler not supporting C99 is VS C compiler afaik. But C is mostly broken under Windows, similar to OpenGL. It works, with a few quirks, but it's not for serious development.